# Inserting non-ASCII characters using the :before pseudo element

Tags: css, pseudo-element, non-ascii-characters

I have an input field inside a span, so that I can put a pound sign before all input fields in a span with the priceField class. However, because the pound symbol is a special character, I can't get it to render properly. I have tried the ascii dec and hex values, the html number & name and the actual symbol. Everything apart from the symbol print out the actual code, whereas the symbol outputs Â£.

Here is my current css:

```
#productEditForm .priceField:before {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    content: "£";
    margin: 9px 4px 9px 2px;
    color: #075946;
}​
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your document's encoding?

Comment: Do you have a specific content encoding set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix the character encoding mismatch (more info would be needed for instructions on how to do that), or you can use the construct "\a3" instead of "£".

Answer (score 3):

There's a mismatch between the stylesheet encoding and your document encoding. Save both as UTF-8 (or another common encoding)

Comment: That's it, `£` in UTF-8 is `0xC2 0xA3`, which renders as `Â£` in Latin-1.